# Hours, minutes and seconds are not showing in my timestamp after converting a datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime column in my csv file that has the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

| TimeCreated |
| --- |
| 7/20/2020 7:59:48 AM |
| 7/20/2020 8:53:32 AM |
| 7/20/2020 8:53:33 AM |
| 7/20/2020 4:32:04 PM |
| 7/21/2020 8:54:50 AM |
| 7/21/2020 8:55:31 AM |
| 7/21/2020 1:42:26 PM |
| 7/21/2020 1:42:26 PM |

I want to convert this so that it reads in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
The Python I am using to try and achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

def format(val):
    df = pd.to_datetime(val, errors='coerce', cache=False).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    try:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(df, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    except:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(df, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return date_time_obj.date()
# Saving the changes to the same column.

df['TimeCreated'] = df['TimeCreated'].apply(lambda x: format(x))

df.to_csv(f'output.csv', index=False, date_format='%s')
```

This works to produce my new column like:

| TimeCreated |
| --- |
| 20/07/2020 |
| 20/07/2020 |
| 20/07/2020 |
| 20/07/2020 |
| 21/07/2020 |
| 21/07/2020 |
| 21/07/2020 |
| 21/07/2020 |

However I cannot see the hours, minutes and seconds.

I am new to using the datetime library so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Return date_time_obj not date_time_obj.date() from the function.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that..

Comment: Basically you just want `df['TimeCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeCreated'])`, you don't need the `datetime` standard lib here. If working with `pandas`, look for built-in functionality - most of the time, that will be more efficient.

Comment: Why is this being marked as a duplicate when it is clearly not?